# Codeigniter form submitting

Tags: forms, codeigniter, onchange

I have a controller which loads a view for inserting records into database. This view contains dropdown select. So when this view is loaded I want to check the dropdown's selected value and do something like this:

```
if($this->input->post('my_select') == FALSE)
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //do something else
}
```

So when this dropdown gets changed I want to reload this and check again. I want to show the view depending on which value was selected. So I want to use onChange="this.form.submit()" but unfortunately this does not work in Codeigniter.

So my question is simply how to do this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming problems. But here you have three questions: i) explain the purpose of MVC models ii) how to submit an HTML form using JavaScript iii) how to process a form submission using CodeIgniter. Consider making your problem more specific and clearer.

Comment: Well thanks... but I know how to submit a form using Javascript... The problem is that "this.form.submit()" just does not work in CI. I also mentioned models because I thought I'm missing something there..

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? The JavaScript submit() method runs in the client (browser) - CI runs on the server and the two are completely independent. Is the server correctly receiving the request from the browser?

Comment: Yes but somehow this event gets blocked...nothing happens. Page does not get reloaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want to use some sort of AJAX call which requests the controller and places the data in properly.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#element').change(function()
{ 
    $.post('index.php/endpoint', function(data)
    {
        // do something here.
        $('#another_element').html(data);
    }
}
```

Your controller can shoot out anything but I prefer that it'd be JSON data. That way you can run `JSON.parse()` on it.

Comment: ok... I get this.. even if I don't use jquery, I can simply make a function and put ajax request in it.